# Sum of factoriais to be equal a given number

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> What is the smallest number of factoriais summed that are needed to be equal an given number **a**? (1 ≤ **a** ≤ 10^5)

Example:

> Input: 10, Output: 3. (10 = 3! + 2! + 2!)
>
> Input: 25, Output: 2. (25 = 4! + 1!)

My code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int a;

int rec(int vet){
    
    int count = 0;
    
    a = a - vet;
        if(a >= vet){
            count++;
            rec(vet);
        }
    count++;
    return count;
}

int main(){
    
    int vet[8] = {1}, count = 0;
    
    cin >> a;
    
    for(int i = 2; i <= 8; i++){
        vet[i-1] = vet[i-2]*i;
    }
    
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
        if(a < vet[i]){
            continue;
        }
        
        count += rec(vet[i]);
    }
    
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

My logic:

> 1°: **a** max is equal to 100000, so the maximum fatorial we have to
> compare is 8!;
>
> 2°: I take a factioral that is equal or nearest small to **a**,
> subtract the factorial from it and count++; If after the subtraction,
> **a** still bigger then my factorial, I do the same step recursively.

This code pass on the base cases, but I got a wrong answer. I wasn't capable to find what case it didn't pass, so I'm here.

Can you find where am I wrong? Or if my solution is not good and I should try another approach.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Step #1, Learn how to use a debugger. Run through each line of code, examine the variables changing, etc.  Post what you have found.  Thanks.

Comment: @OldProgrammer The problem is he seems to submitting it to some online judge that doesn't tell him the test case it fails for.

Comment: @OldProgrammer That's the point. I tried to debug with many inputs and all of then are correct. I'm here because I didn't find what input is causing the trouble.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yep!

Comment: There is probably a case where two smaller factorials added together give you the number when using your approach takes 3 or more numbers.

Comment: Ok, but we don't know which test case it fails for either.

Comment: Okay So I see a problem with the rec function. The count variable is local. Meaning if you call rec from rec the count will be different. So when the count is incremented inside it wont affect the count you are maintaining in the outer call. I would suggest a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried to find some example that fits, but I didn't find. Can you provide me some? And thanks for the help!

Comment: @Katreque, 18. The failing case is 18!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, the issue is with the rec function. Due to rec being local, the count is not being incremented correctly.

A simple solution would be to replace the rec function as follows

```
int rec(int vec) {
    int count = a / vec;
    a = a % vec;
    return count;
}
```

Edit : for a failing case try 18. The solution will be 3 but you will get 2.
I guess you can figure out how this logic works. If not you could do it with a loop.

Comment: Apreciated! I didn't think in such good and simple solution for this problem. And 18 were the problem. Again, thank a lot for the help and time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is easily solved by a recursive approach.

Here is checked code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int n) {
        return n<=1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
    }


int MinFact(int number)
{
            static int num_of_facts;
            int a = 1;
            if (number)
            {
                        while(factorial(a+1)<=number)a++;
                        cout << a << "!" << endl;
                        num_of_facts++;
                        MinFact((number-factorial(a)));
            }
            return num_of_facts;
}


int main()
{
            int num;
            cout << "Enter number" << endl;
            cin >> num;
            num = MinFact(num);
            cout << "Number of factorials: " << num;
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That's another good way to solve this problem. And I liked your fatorial func. Great ideia! Again, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Edited. Now it's returnes number of factorials.